# How can I place select and insert code in the same PHP file while using AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am new to Ajax and Jquery. Having learnt the fundamental concepts, I tried to make a PHP application wherein values could be inserted and shown right below it with a click of a button using Ajax, PHP and Jquery. But things couldn't pan out and I ended up making 4 files namely, insert_frontend, insert_backend, select_frontend, select_backend.

I want insert and select code to be placed in one backend file and similarly, having only 1 frontend.

Code is mentioned below:

insert_frontend.php:

```
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#insert').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
            url:"insert_backend.php",
            method:"post",
            data:$('form').serialize(),
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(strMsg){
                $('#Imsg').html(strMsg);
            }   

    })  
})


})
</script>
<body>
<div id="Imsg"></div>
<div id="Smsg"></div>
<form method="post" action="#">
<table>
<tr><th>Name</th><td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td></tr>
<tr><th>Address</th><td><input type="text" name="address" id="address"></td></tr>
<tr><th>Contact</th><td><input type="text" name="contact" id="contact"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="Insert" id="insert" value="insert"></td></tr>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<input type="submit" name="select" id="select" value="select">
</body>
```

insert_backend.php:

```
<body>
<?php

/*insert start*/
$name=$_POST['name'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$contact=$_POST['contact'];

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testajax");
$data=mysqli_query($con,"insert into student values(null,'$name','$address','$contact')");
if($data==true)
{
    echo "value inserted";  
}
else
{
    echo "insert error";    
}
/*insert end*/

?>
</body>
```

select_frontend.php:

```
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#select').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
        url:"select_backend.php",
        dataType:"html",
        success:function(strMsg){
            $('#Smsg').html(strMsg);    
        }                   
    })
})
})
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="submit" name="select" id="select" value="Select">
<div id="Smsg"></div>
</body>
```

select_backend.php:

```
<body>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testajax");
$data1=mysqli_query($con,"select * from student");
$col=mysqli_num_fields($data1);
echo '<table>';
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data1))
{
    echo '<tr>';
    for($i=0;$i<$col;$i++)
    {
        echo '<td>'.$row[$i].'</td>';   
    }
    echo '</tr>';

}
echo '</table>';
?>
</body>
```

#### Whosoever downvoted me, please give me the reason for a downvote so that I could improve.

Comment: What error or problem you are getting?

Comment: I want insert and select code to be placed in one backend file and similarly, having only 1 frontend.

Comment: Instead I would recommend removing the javascript from the html and splitting the html in a template and separate views. More files instead of less, but easier to maintain.

Comment: You are right, I can place the jquery code in a separate file. But I want to place insert and select code in one file instead of two separate files. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, I would recommend removing the javascript from the html and splitting the html in a template and separate views. More files instead of less, but easier to maintain.

That also applies to the controllers to select and insert the information.

However, if you want to put these together, you can take advantage of the different http methods used:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === 'POST') {
    // a POST request was made, execute your insert 
else {
    // a GET request was made, execute your select
}
```

You could even add more methods like `DELETE` to put that action in the same controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me to the right direction. The problem is, I am new to the whole PHP, Jquery and Ajax thing. Although I can understand using a framework could ease out things in the long run but right now I am focused on doing this using core PHP functionality. Apart from that, I may sound stupid but I really don't know about "$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === 'POST'". Could you plz do me the code and point me to the resources to get some knowledge about the same. Thanks yet again.

Comment: @Don'tDownvoteMe I am not talking about using frameworks. You just need to put the insert code (all of it) where I put the insert comment and the select code where I put the select comment. You / jQuery are making a GET request to the server in `insert_frontend.php` and a POST request in `select_frontend.php` so it will work automatically.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, I got it working, Plz help me to the last bit, I want the output for the select statement to be shown only after a button click. A user was kind enough to help me with it in their answer but I am not able to figure out a way to insert the click event into the code(lots of curly braces and parentheses) in Jquery. Also plz point me to some resources that could give me more knowledge about $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === 'POST' and similar.

Comment: How should I put delete and update in the same controller as you mentioned above along with insert and select?

Comment: Thanks anyways man! Managed to put two buttons with different functionalities(click). But still struggling with the delete and update concept in HTTP methods. Would appreciate if you could help.

Answer (score 1):

Try following script:

I hope it will work.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#insert').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
            url:"insert_backend.php",
            method:"post",
            data:$('form').serialize(),
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(strMsg){
                $.ajax({
                url:"select_backend.php",
                dataType:"html",
                success:function(strMsg){
                    $('#Smsg').html(strMsg);    
                }                   
            });
                $('#Imsg').html(strMsg);
            }   
            });  
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks,the above mentioned code works fine but I want two things to explicitly happen. First, the output should be shown only using a button click other than insert button. Second, I want to place insert and select code in 1 backend file instead of two.